# Как получить данные (имя, фамилию и т.д.) авторизованного пользователя через VK API?

Tags: java, android, android-vksdk

Как получить данные (имя, фамилию и т.д.) авторизованного пользователя через VK API?

Вот мой код:

```
public class VkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String [] scope = new String[]{VKScope.MESSAGES,VKScope.FRIENDS,VKScope.WALL};
    private  String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vk);
        VKSdk.login(this, scope);
    }


    VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
            if (newToken == null) {
                // VKAccessToken is invalid
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountActivity.class);
                VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(); ;
                VKAPI.

              //  startActivity(intent1);
                // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),res + "Пользователь успешно авторизовался",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Произошла ошибка авторизации",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String token = VKSdk.getAccessToken().accessToken;
VKParameters parameters = VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, token);

VKRequest request = new VKRequest("account.getProfileInfo", parameters);

request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener(MainActivity.this)
{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);

        String status = "";

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");

            String first_name = jsonObject.getString("first_name");
            String last_name = jsonObject.getString("last_name");
            String screen_name = jsonObject.getString("screen_name");
            status = jsonObject.getString("status");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

Чтобы использовать другие параметры, обращайтесь к запросам user

```
String token = VKSdk.getAccessToken().accessToken;
VKParameters parameters = VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, token,
        VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_100",
        VKApiConst.NAME_CASE, "nom");

VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(parameters);

request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener(MainActivity.this)
{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        String photo_100 = null;
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.json.getJSONArray("response");
            JSONObject jsonObject =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
            photo_100 = jsonObject.getString("photo_100");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо код работает!